# Остановка скрипта по приказу контроллера

Tags: javascript, asp.net, mvc

В проекте asp.net mvc есть скрипт, крутящий заставку, пока происходит действие (в данном случае крутится заставка после нажатия кнопки в течении 5 секунд). Также при нажатии кнопки действие идет в контроллер, и там уже выполняется алгоритм, который возвращает данные во View. Как можно сделать так, чтобы получить приказ из контролера о том, что надо прекратить крутить заставку после получения данных?

```
<script>
    jQuery(function ($) {
        //подвешиваем на событие клик по кнопке
        $('#button1').on('click', function (e) {
            //отключение ее
            $(e.currentTarget).attr('disabled', true);
            // показываем процесс закгрузки
            $('.loader').toggleClass('hide');

            // подвешиваем паузу на 5 секунд
            setTimeout(function () {
                // скрываем процесс загрузки
                $('.loader').toggleClass('hide');
                // делаем кнопку активной
                $(e.currentTarget).attr('disabled', false);

            }, 5000)
        });
    });
</script>
```

После нажатия на кнопку Ajax перегружает часть View.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index1", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "Post",
    UpdateTargetId = "main",
}))
{
    @Html.TextBox("departure", null, new { placeholder = "1" })
    @Html.TextBox("arrival", null, new { placeholder = "1" })
    <button type="submit" value="Найти" class="small-input" id="button1">Найти</button>
}

public ActionResult Index1(string departure,string arrival)
{
    return View(GlobalWay);
}
```

Comment: где вызывается контроллер? в предоставленном коде только заставка показывается

Comment: Добавил. Вопрос тот же. Как сделать так что бы заставка крутилась только то время которое будет работать код в контроллере?

Comment: вам стоит посмотреть свойства [AjaxOptions.LoadingElementDuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/gg401870(v=vs.118).aspx), [AjaxOptions.LoadingElementId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd460278(v=vs.118).aspx), а так же [AjaxOptions.OnSuccess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd460367(v=vs.118).aspx) и [AjaxOptions.OnComplete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd470559(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: Спасибо. Помог LoadingElementId = id, где id = id html заставки. А скрипт верхний можно не использовать вообще.

Comment: если вы сами нашли ответ на свой вопрос, опубликуйте его, и пометьте как выбранный. Чтобы помочь будущим пользователям с похожей проблемой

Comment: Сделано. Еще раз спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на данный вопрос:
Добавляем LoadingElementId = "loader" в AjaxOptions.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index1", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "Post",
    UpdateTargetId = "main",
    LoadingElementId = "loader"
}))
{
    @Html.TextBox("departure", null, new { placeholder = "1" })
    @Html.TextBox("arrival", null, new { placeholder = "1" })
    <button type="submit" value="Найти" class="small-input" id="button1">Найти</button>
}
```

и в html делаем блок id заставки.

```
<div id="loader" class="loader hide"></div>
```